# How to Add test results to a test run in VSTS using Rest API programatically

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've got API link for this task

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version={version}
```

**https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#add-test-results-to-a-test-run**

I need program to do through API way.

Alternative, i've tried with program below

```
public void GetResult()
        {
            var u = new Uri("https://{UserAccount}.visualstudio.com");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "MyPAT"));
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
            int testpointid = 100;
            string teamProject = "Project12345";
            RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "APIRun7", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("100"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid });
            TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;
            TestCaseResultUpdateModel testCaseUpdate = new TestCaseResultUpdateModel() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "Passed", TestResult = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("100000") };
            //var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResultUpdateModel[] { testCaseUpdate }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
            RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
            TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel ,teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;
        }​
```

I got the error:

> cannot convert from  'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.TestCaseResultUpdateModel[]'
>   to 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.TestCaseResult[]'

Comment: You are using 15.0 package, so change the code like this:TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };
            var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;

Comment: Remove TestCaseResultUpdateModel testCaseUpdate = new TestCaseResultUpdateModel() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "Passed", TestResult = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("100000") };

Comment: @starian - I've modified code as per your suggestion. I've encountered **AggregateException** error. Still our code fails :-(

I've added try catch(AggregateException) and execution goes into catch block.

Comment: How do you get the test point id? Using this rest api to get test point id https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/points#get-a-list-of-test-points.

Comment: On the other hand, you need to check innerException: (catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);})

Comment: @starain - I got the output `Test plan {0} not found`.  

I suspect, we have issue with testpoint id. I think testpoint id and our original testCase ID are not same? i used testcase id as testpoint id. Plz comment

Comment: They are different. Refer to these thread to create test plan, test suite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561306/add-test-result-to-a-test-runtestcase-in-vsts

Comment: This should be tagged with [tfs-sdk], because the classes you are using are part of the tfs-sdk / tfs client libraries (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
     var u = new Uri("https://{My Account}.visualstudio.com");
     VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));
     var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
     var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
     int testpointid = 1;
     string teamProject = "MyProjectName";
     RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "TestCase Name", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("TestPlan Id"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid });
     TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;

     TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };

     var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
     RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
     TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;

}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Note: Points to Configure, if needed

1. Install Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package [
   Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
   -Version 15.112.1].
2. Install Test Manager extension - Create test plan, test suite in
   Test tab.
3. Testpointid is Testcase no [order/index of testcase in
       test plan], not testcase id.
4. Name is Testcase name, testrun id is auto captures through
   testpointid[order like 1,2,3...]

Comment: @starain - Your help very helpful, truely appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps:

1. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package
2. Simple code

:

```
 var u = new Uri("https://[account].visualstudio.com");
                VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "[personal access token]"));                
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
                var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

                string teamProject = "scrum2015";
                int testRunId = 286;
                int testSuiteId = 591;
                RunUpdateModel runmodelUpdate = new RunUpdateModel(state: "InProgress");

                TestRun testRunUpdateResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(teamProject, testRunId, runmodelUpdate).Result;
                var results = testClient.GetTestResultsAsync(teamProject, testRunId).Result.First();
               var testPoints= testClient.GetPointsAsync(teamProject,Int32.Parse(testRunUpdateResult.Plan.Id), testSuiteId).Result;
                TestRun testRunUpdate = testClient.GetTestRunByIdAsync(teamProject, testRunId).Result;

                TestResultCreateModel newTestResult = new TestResultCreateModel() { TestCase=new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference(id: results.TestCase.Id.ToString()), TestPoint = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference(id: testPoints.First().Id.ToString()), Outcome="Failed",State= "Completed" };
               var updateResult= testClient.AddTestResultsToTestRunAsync(new TestResultCreateModel[] { newTestResult }, teamProject, testRunId).Result;
                RunUpdateModel runmodelUpdate2 = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");

                TestRun testRunUpdateResult2 = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(teamProject, testRunId, runmodelUpdate2).Result;
```

Comment: @starian - Good Start for me.

TestSuite(testSuiteId) Doesnt exist in my VSTS. Just Testcase directly. Could you please help with modified/updated code accordingly....
This code would be very useful for others. Don't Overide this(Probably could append the other one)

Comment: I've updated my code and error. Please take a look.In case if any find any update/error resolution, your help would be appreciated

Comment: @Shalem No, the test points must be in the TestSuite, you need to create a TestSuite and add/create test case.