# Add Test Result to a test run(testcase) in VSTS

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to add test result to a testcase in VSTS. I'm new to VSTS and not sure what went wrong with my code

```
var ur = new Uri("https://{myaccount}.visualstudio.com");
VssCredentials cr = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "XXXXX"));
var connection = new VssConnection(ur, cr);
var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
int testpointid = 123;
string teamProject = "myproj";
RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "name123", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("123"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid });
TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("100000") };
TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };
var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Success");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495814/how-to-add-test-results-to-a-test-run-in-vsts-using-rest-api-programatically*)  similar but dint get answer.

## Note:

I don't find option to create Test Suite and then test case in that. Just created test case directly. Is it mandate to create Test Suite? If so, how?

Comment: My code is much similar and i got **AggregateException** error. Could someone help with us?

Comment: Does someone tried through API provided

`https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version={version}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        try
        {
            var u = new Uri("https://{My Account}.visualstudio.com");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
            int testpointid = 1;
            string teamProject = "MyProjectName";
            RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "TestCase Name", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("TestPlan Id"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid });
            TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;

            TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };

            var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
            RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
            TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;

        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);

        }
```

Note: Instructions to configure

1. Install Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package

`Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version 15.112.1`

2. Install Test Manager extension, Create test plan, test suite in Test tab
3. `testpointid` is TestCase number (i.e. order/index of testcase in test plan) and not the ID of the TestCase
4. `name` is Testcase name, `testrun.Id` is auto-captured through testpointid (first index being `1`)

Comment: @starain - Thanks a lot. Your suggestions helped me in suceeding. I've summarized your suggestions in Note Section.

Answer (score 1):

The test suite is required. There are some ways to create test suite:

Way 1:

1. Install [Test Manager extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web)
2. Create test plan, test suite in Test tab

Way 2: Using MTM to create test plan, test suite: [Organizing Test Cases Using Test Suites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286738(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note: MTM is include in Visual Studio (e.g. VS Ultimate, Premium, Enterprise (2015) and visual studio test professional).

Way 3:

1. Go to backlog board
2. Add test

[image]

3. Go to Test page and check test plan, suite

[image]

Comment: Nice article to create Test Suite & Test Plan