# How to add/update individual result to each test step in testcase of VSTS/TFS programatically

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm able to update test result to testcase in VSTS through program.
[Test Case Result Updation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561306/add-test-result-to-a-test-runtestcase-in-vsts)

Now, i want to update the result of each test step in test case. Couldn't find any related info. Please help

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: @starain-MSFT - Sorry, for the delayed update. we've tried your solution. Encountered with error **TypeLoadException was unhandled**. Error reads as 

`Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TFStringComparer' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`

Any Suggestion please?

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package? Can you are a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: I'm using [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Client 15.112.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.112.1).

Comment: The line of code, where i've encountered the error is: 
`ITestPlan _plan = _testproject.TestPlans.Find(123);`

Comment: Using Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client instead. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Comment: How do you add the hyperlink to the text in comment?

Comment: Place your text in [text] and hyperlink in (link).  Syntax:
[Text](http:\\google.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way is using client API:

Simple sample:

```
int testpointid = 176;
            var u = new Uri("https://[account].visualstudio.com");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "[pat]"));
            TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject _testproject = test_service.GetTeamProject("scrum2015");
            ITestPlan _plan = _testproject.TestPlans.Find(115);
            ITestRun testRun = _plan.CreateTestRun(false);
            testRun.Title = "apiTest";
            ITestPoint point = _plan.FindTestPoint(testpointid);
            testRun.AddTestPoint(point, test_service.AuthorizedIdentity);
            testRun.Save();
            testRun.Refresh();
            ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
            ITestIterationResult iterationResult;

            foreach (ITestCaseResult result in results)
            {
                iterationResult = result.CreateIteration(1);
                foreach (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestStep testStep in result.GetTestCase().Actions)
                {
                    ITestStepResult stepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);
                    stepResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed; //you can assign different states here
                    iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
                }
                iterationResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
                result.Save(true);
            }
            testRun.State = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestRunState.Completed;
            results.Save(true);
```

Regarding REST api, the necessary information is stored in **actionResults** of **iterationDetails** (TestCaseResult.IterationDetails), you can try specify **IterationDetails** to **TestCaseResult** and update test result.

You can check the details of a test result by using [Get a Test Result with DetailInclude](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-test-result) (detailsToInclude=Iterations)

Comment: How to view the individual test step results in the test case? I could find only the final result of test case/test run in outcome column of test suite listed but couldn't find the test result of each individual test step.

Comment: @srinivasp Many ways to get test step results: 1. As I said that using Get a Test Result with DetailInclude 2. Web access, Test > Runs >Enter a test run> Go>Test results>Double click a test result>Check in details> 3. MTM, open MTM and connect to TFS and select test plan>Test>Run tests>Select a test suite>Select a test point > Click View Results

Comment: Finally, using [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) resolved the error. I'm able to update the result of each test step in test case.