# How to retrieve no.of teststeps in a test case and dynamically update individual result to each test step in testcase of VSTS/TFS programatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm having multiple Test steps for each testcase in VSTS. I want to programmatically find no.of test steps in a testcase and manually update test result(Pass/Fail) for each teststep dynamically. **So that I can trace which teststep got failed in a test case run**

I've found [TestSteps result updation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697226/how-to-add-update-individual-result-to-each-test-step-in-testcase-of-vsts-tfs-pr/44713155#44713155) program which updates testcase's teststep result (Pass/Fail). This can't either determine no.of teststeps in a testcase or dynamically update teststep results individually(through console)

Comment: How do you want to update teststeps results dynamically? Can you provide a sample? To determine no. of teststeps in a test case, you can result.GetTestCase().Actions.Count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've programmed successfully. Use nuget Package [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide your Test Plan id");
        int testplanid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide your testpoint id");
        int testpointid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var u = new Uri("Your account url");
        VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "Your PAT"));
        TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
        ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
        ITestManagementTeamProject _testproject = test_service.GetTeamProject("Your Project name");
        ITestPlan _plan = _testproject.TestPlans.Find(testplanid);
        ITestRun testRun = _plan.CreateTestRun(false);
        testRun.Title = "TestStep Updation Trail1";
        ITestPoint point = _plan.FindTestPoint(testpointid);
        testRun.AddTestPoint(point, test_service.AuthorizedIdentity);
        testRun.Save();
        testRun.Refresh();
        ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
        ITestIterationResult iterationResult;

        foreach (ITestCaseResult result in results)
        {
            iterationResult = result.CreateIteration(1);
            foreach (ITestStep testStep in result.GetTestCase().Actions)
            {
                String TeststepResult;
                ITestStepResult stepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the TestStep Outcome:");
                TeststepResult= Console.ReadLine();
                if (TeststepResult=="Passed" || TeststepResult=="passed" || TeststepResult=="pass")
                {
                    stepResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed; 
                }
                else
                {
                    stepResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Failed;
                }
                iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
            }
            String TestResult;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Overall TestCase Result [Passed/Failed] :");
            TestResult= Console.ReadLine();
            if (TestResult == "Passed" || TestResult == "passed" || TestResult=="pass")
            {
                iterationResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
            }
            else
            {
                iterationResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Failed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Failed;
            }
            result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
            result.Save(true);
        }
        testRun.State = TestRunState.Completed;
        results.Save(true);
        Console.WriteLine("Sucesfully Updated TestCase TestSteps");
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

A Test Case is just another Work Item type and the Steps are simply a specially formatted string field (see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/build-test-integration#build-and-test-data-fields).

Comment: Do you have any programatic help?