# How to create, delete and update Test Steps listed in VSTS Test Cases

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops

We are working on building an approach that automatically update test suite's execution metrics onto the VSTS server. After going through the REST API document for VSTS, we were able to do the following using those automated APIs

- Create a Test RUN with desired list of existing test cases
- Update the Test RESULTS (outcome and status) for the above created Test RUN

Now it is possible to update whether the Test Case is Pass, Fail or any other available outcomes. But **we are looking for an automated approach with which we can update the status of each Test Step inside each Test Case to Pass, Fail or any other available outcomes**.

Hope I have explained our pain area in more understandable way.

Please reply your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Steps listed in VSTS Test Cases still belongs to test result.

If you get a test result with parameter `detailsToInclude=Iterations', you will see there is "actionResults" to determine test steps outcome:

```
Get https://xxx.visualstudio.com/TestCase/_apis/test/runs/xx/results/xx?api-version=3.0-preview&detailsToInclude=Iterations
```

But I've tried update "actionResults" with REST api [Update test results for a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#update-test-results-for-a-test-run), and found it doesn't support update "actionResults". Your requirement can not be achieved with rest api.

Instead of REST api, you can use the client api as this case mentioned: [How to add/update individual result to each test step in testcase of VSTS/TFS programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697226/how-to-add-update-individual-result-to-each-test-step-in-testcase-of-vsts-tfs-pr/44713155)

Simple sample:

```
int testpointid = 176;
            var u = new Uri("https://[account].visualstudio.com");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "[pat]"));
            TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject _testproject = test_service.GetTeamProject("scrum2015");
            ITestPlan _plan = _testproject.TestPlans.Find(115);
            ITestRun testRun = _plan.CreateTestRun(false);
            testRun.Title = "apiTest";
            ITestPoint point = _plan.FindTestPoint(testpointid);
            testRun.AddTestPoint(point, test_service.AuthorizedIdentity);
            testRun.Save();
            testRun.Refresh();
            ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
            ITestIterationResult iterationResult;

            foreach (ITestCaseResult result in results)
            {
                iterationResult = result.CreateIteration(1);
                foreach (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestStep testStep in result.GetTestCase().Actions)
                {
                    ITestStepResult stepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);
                    stepResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed; //you can assign different states here
                    iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
                }
                iterationResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
                result.Save(true);
            }
            testRun.State = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestRunState.Completed;
            results.Save(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay in response. I am able to update the test step status with the provided solution. Is there any way like this to upload screenshot to the corresponding test step. If yes please reply. thanks in advance