# TFS/Azure DevOps Testcase step outcome update using Azure DevOps API

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the azure DevOps API to update the test results automatically after test automation run. From the documents, I am able to update the overall outcome of the test case using the below API. But I have a requirement to update each test step outcome result as well for which I didn't find any help in azure documentation. Is there a way to update test case steps outcome using Azure DevOps API?
API used to update the test case outcome is 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Hi @Rajeev nair Did you check out below answer? please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Since the API is not available to update the test step outcome, we have raised it as a request and now its converted as a feature request
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/929411/tfsazure-devops-testcase-step-outcome-update-using.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/935832/update-case-step-outcome-using-rest-api.html
Unfortunately there is no sufficient vote to prioritize this issue implementation

Answer (score 2):

The test case steps is defined in **[actionResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#testiterationdetailsmodel)** of **TestIterationDetailsModel** in **iterationDetails** of the Request body **TestCaseResult**.

You can first use [Get test results Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and specify the `detailsToInclude=Iterations` to get the detailed `iterationDetails` and `actionResults` information of the TestCaseResults. And then you can construct your Request body and modify the `iterationDetails` and `actionResults` outcome according the TestCaseResults.

`"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=Iterations&api-version=5.1"`

I found an example to [update the test step result in C# client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697226/how-to-add-update-individual-result-to-each-test-step-in-testcase-of-vsts-tfs-pr), you can check it out. Hope above helps.