# AutomatedTestName must be specified for automated test runs for AddTestResults Azure DevOps API call

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to create test results in Azure DevOps in .NET as simply as possible given a CSV input, and it looks like the fastest way is to first create an empty Test Run, then add new test results to the test run.

I've tested by hardcoding and also running Postman but seem to get the same error message both via REST and the SDK:

> AutomatedTestName must be specified for automated test runs when
>   neither TestPointId nor TestCaseId has been specified.

Here's the .NET code:

```
var testCase = await testPlanClient.GetTestCaseAsync(_teamProject, {planId}, {suiteId}, "1141");

var testPoint = testCase[0].PointAssignments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ConfigurationId == testConfiguration.Id);
var pointId = testPoint.Id;

var run = new RunCreateModel(name: testRun.Name, state: "NotStarted", isAutomated: false, plan: new ShallowReference({planid}), pointIds:new int[] { 1654 });

...

testResultList.Add(new TestApi.TestCaseResult()
                {
                    TestCaseTitle = testResult.TestCaseTitle,
                    TestCase = new ShallowReference(id: testResult.TestCaseId.ToString()),
                    TestPoint = new ShallowReference(id: "1654"),
                    TestCaseReferenceId = testResult.TestCaseId,
                    Outcome = SetOutcome(testResult.Outcome),
                    Configuration = new ShallowReference(id: testConfiguration.Id.ToString()),
                    CreatedDate = testResult.CreatedDate,
                    StartedDate = testResult.StartedDate,
                    CompletedDate = testResult.CompletedDate
                });
            }           

List<TestApi.TestCaseResult> createdTestResults = new List<TestApi.TestCaseResult>();
createdTestResults = await testClient.AddTestResultsToTestRunAsync(testResultList.ToArray(), _teamProject, testRunId);
```

Postman:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1

[
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "testcase1",
    "testPoint": {
        "id": 17
    },
    "testCase": {
        "id": 1141
    },
    "priority": 1,
    "outcome": "Passed"
  }
]
```

I've put in both TestPointId and TestCaseId in the above examples and both seem to not work if I still get the same error message. I've looked into similar answers like: [How to Add test results to a test run in VSTS using Rest API programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495814/how-to-add-test-results-to-a-test-run-in-vsts-using-rest-api-programatically) but they all seem to be using existing test results, where I just want to add new test results to a run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because your Test Run is automated you need to provide the property `AutomatedTestName` to the `TestCaseResults`, for example:

```
TestCaseResults results = new TestCaseReults()
{
     TestCaseTitle = "test",
     AutomatedTestName = "name",
     TestCase = new ShallowReference(id: "32"),
     TestPoint = new ShallowReference(id: "1"),
     Outcome = "Passed"
}
List<TestCaseResult> list = new List<TestCaseResult>();
list.add(results);
var response = test.AddTestResultsToTestRunAsync(list.ToArray(), "project", 3214 // Test Run ID).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and for cleaning up my question). Unfortunately it looks like when I put that in, I get "automatedTestName should not be specified for manual run." I'll include code that I used for TestRun.

Comment: @m00nbeam360.0 Oh ok, can you make the test run not "manually"? you just need to add `isAuutomated: true` when you create the `RunCreateModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it looks like an automated test run/result can be created but won't link with a test case, have you tried that before to get it to work?

Comment: What is your final solution?